# Search from drop down option in ruby and display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

How to search something from drop down option in ruby and display?

```
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
        validates :name, :email, :designation,  presence: true
        validates :email, uniqueness: true

        def self.search(search)
            if search
        find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE '%?%'", search[:name])
        else 
            find(:all)
    end
    end
```

Comment: I'm sure you should add [ruby] as a tag.  It's more important than model at least

Comment: You have unmatched quotes in `:conditions`.